# How do I make a local DB for my application?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, localhost

Good day! I am working on a local application in nodejs that will do the following:

- Sell items and record the sale
- Compare previous sales/orders/profitability to give the individual items rankings
- Make orders based on those rankings

I have some self taught experience in coding mongoose databases. I am also self taught in general, so I don't know what to do in my case where I want to be able to make schemas and use methods I am familiar with except locally. So my question is, are there db libraries for local applications? I really hope I described the question well, because (being self taught) my terminology can be a little unclear.

Comment: If you want to use MongoDB, then you could just install the database from the official website. This link should help you:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however I decided I want some of my own... flavor... in handling data. Perhaps it's worse than using a json localdb npm but it gets things done the way I want. So I have decided to go with the more time consuming but personalized route.